# android app for store pictures and gps location and description

Tags: android, gps, location, photo, store

I'm new here and I don't know if I post on to the right forum.

I'd like to do an application.
Application could capture a photo and GPS location and store everything together in database. I could add a description to picture next time when I want. This would be like my diary with photos and locations where I was (trip). Next time I could look and search for the picture or location and see the details of the description I wrote.

For now I don't heave an android phone so I'm doing just in emulator.

Any idea how to done this app?

Thanks Matej

Answer (score 0):

I'd just take the picture, find a way to tag it, and upload it to a site like [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/), especially if you aren't too worried about privacy. They can do the database calls on location, date, and any other key words you might come up with. Just a thought. Here's a bit of information on the various pieces you'd need to do:

1. [Taking a photo with Android](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/8683)
2. [How to upload a picture to Flikr in Android](http://www.anddev.org/flickr_upload_in_android-t9631.html)

Comment: thx for the reply. Do you heave any sample code for this? I'm a beginner and if yo do, vould you be so kind and post the whole code. Even changed manifest file. If there are yust peaces of code I can't put it togerther.

Comment: No sample code at all (This is a rather complex tool), but I can give you a few pieces to nibble on. I'll just add them to the answer.